# Android my App crash after set button disabled

Tags: android, button, crash

My app crashes after I pressed a button.

My code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_print_trans"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:onClick="OnClickPrintSimpleApiTest"
    android:text="PRINT"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

and:

```
public void OnClickPrintSimpleApiTest(View view) {
    final Button BTN_print = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_print_trans);
    BTN_print.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    BTN_print.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Whenever an app crashes there will be a stack trace in the logcat. You should always post the stack with your question. That will keep us from guessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the OP defined the `onClick` method `OnClickPrintSimpleApiTest` as an attribute in their xml layout file as:

`android:onClick="OnClickPrintSimpleApiTest"`

They do not need to get a reference to the `Button` using `findViewById()`.

The `Button` view is passed to the `OnClickPrintSimpleApiTest()` method as the parameter "view". Therefore, simply do this:

```
public void OnClickPrintSimpleApiTest(View view) {
    Button BTN_print = (Button) view
    BTN_print.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    BTN_print.setEnabled(false);
}
```